# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Hi all I'm new in Flutter , I'm trying to fetch api data into listview, got the following error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' , type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' and I does not getting values from this codes. Here Problem is Data not showing here.

```
class MyClient extends MyClientService {
  final int id, clientId, acceptedBy, pincode;
  final double latitude, longitude;
  final String perpose,
      details,
      when,
      name,
      mobile,
      email,
      orgName,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      country,
      clientIp,
      device,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt;

  MyClient({
    ...
  });

  factory MyClient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyClient(
      ...
    );
  }

  Future<List<MyClient>> fetchClients() async {
    var datas = await super.fetchDatas();
    List dataList = json.decode(datas);
    print(dataList); // Data Getting here
    List<MyClient> clients =
        dataList.map((req) => MyClient.fromJson(req)).toList();
    print(clients); // Here nothing
    return clients;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is of variable type mismatch so one way you can proceed is in factory method parse the string data in your required type like this to all the variables which are declared as non string in your modal class

```
factory MyClient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return MyClient(
  id: int.parse(json['id']),
  clientId: int.parse(json['client_id']),
   longitude: double.parse(json['longitude']),
 );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here have Object type was missing. That means Some data comes from API as String. But That is Declare as int. Show the problems is data mis match.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:PandeetApp/services/myclient.dart';

class MyClient extends MyClientService {
  final int id, clientId, acceptedBy, pincode;
  final double latitude, longitude;
  final String perpose,
      details,
      when,
      name,
      mobile,
      email,
      orgName,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      country,
      clientIp,
      device,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt;

  MyClient({
    this.id,
    this.clientId,
    this.perpose,
    this.details,
    this.when,
    this.acceptedBy,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.email,
    this.orgName,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.pincode,
    this.clientIp,
    this.device,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory MyClient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyClient(
      id: json['id'],
      clientId: json['client_id'],
      perpose: json['perpose'],
      details: json['details'],
      when: json['when'],
      acceptedBy: json['accepted_by'],
      name: json['name'],
      mobile: json['mobile'],
      email: json['email'],
      orgName: json['org_name'],
      address: json['address'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      pincode: json['pincode'],
      country: json['country'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      clientIp: json['client_ip'],
      device: json['device'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
    );
  }

  Future<List<MyClient>> fetchClients() async {
    var datas = await super.fetchDatas();
    List dataList = json.decode(datas);
    List<MyClient> clients =
        dataList.map((req) => MyClient.fromJson(req)).toList();
    return clients;
  }
}
```

Instead of

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:PandeetApp/services/myclient.dart';

class MyClient extends MyClientService {
  final int id, clientId, acceptedBy;
  final double latitude, longitude;
  final String perpose,
      details,
      when,
      name,
      mobile,
      email,
      orgName,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      pincode,
      country,
      clientIp,
      device,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt;

  MyClient({
    this.id,
    this.clientId,
    this.perpose,
    this.details,
    this.when,
    this.acceptedBy,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.email,
    this.orgName,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.pincode,
    this.clientIp,
    this.device,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory MyClient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyClient(
      id: json['id'],
      clientId: json['client_id'],
      perpose: json['perpose'],
      details: json['details'],
      when: json['when'],
      acceptedBy: json['accepted_by'],
      name: json['name'],
      mobile: json['mobile'],
      email: json['email'],
      orgName: json['org_name'],
      address: json['address'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      pincode: json['pincode'],
      country: json['country'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      clientIp: json['client_ip'],
      device: json['device'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
    );
  }

  Future<List<MyClient>> fetchClients() async {
    var datas = await super.fetchDatas();
    List dataList = json.decode(datas);
    List<MyClient> clients =
        dataList.map((req) => MyClient.fromJson(req)).toList();
    return clients;
  }
}
```