# How to fix type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project I am trying to get the following json API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "active": false,
        "name": "Flat",
        "user": 10,
        "workout": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "active": false,
        "name": "Inclined",
        "user": 10,
        "workout": 4
    }
]
```

I have created the following exercises_model.dart:

```
// To parse required this JSON data, do
//
//     final exercisesModel = exercisesModelFromJson(jsonString);
 
import 'dart:convert';
 
List<Exercises_Model> ExercisesModelFromJson(dynamic decodedResponse) =>
    List<Exercises_Model>.from(
        decodedResponse.map((x) => Exercises_Model.fromJson(x)));
 
String exercisesModelToJson(List<Exercises_Model> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
 
class Exercises_Model {
  Exercises_Model({
    required this.id,
    required this.active,
    required this.name,
    required this.user,
    required this.workout,
  });
 
  int id;
  bool active;
  String name;
  int user;
  int workout;
 
  factory Exercises_Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      Exercises_Model(
        // id: json["id"],
        // active: json["active"],
        // name: json["name"],
        // user: json["user"],
        // workout: json["workout"],
        id: int.parse(json["id"]),
        active: json["active"],
        name: json["name"],
        user: int.parse(json["user"]),
        workout: int.parse(json["workout"]),
      );
 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "active": active,
        "name": name,
        "user": user,
        "workout": workout,
      };
}
```

Whenever I try to get the API I run into this error:

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I am note sure how to fix it I have tried following this answer [type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590840/type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int) but it did not work. My question why I am getting this error although I have set the int

Comment: because you have set it to int and the data is of type string and is expecting it to be string so it gives you this error either set it to string or parse it to int whichever suits you well or you can also add `.toString()` and change the type from int to string i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int.parse(json["id"])
```

`int.parse` takes a string but the provided type is already `int`.

Replace that with:

```
int.parse(json["id"].toString())
```

You will also need to change `user` and `workout`.